# Joomla Smart Search not enabled in Components

Tags: joomla

I want to use Joomla Smart Search.

I am using Joomla 3.9.3
I have enabled the "Content Smart Search" plugin...But under "Components" I cannot find the Smart Seacrh and I cannot edit its setting (but I can see the search module).

How can I "install" this component?

Answer (score 0):

Go to /administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=manage and search for smart search. If it is disabled, then enable it.
Also double check if you are not using a custom back end menu, where smart search is not added. For a test revert back to the default one which has all components enabled.

Comment: yes, it is installed and enabled, an no, not using some custom backend menus...strange indeed. however, looks like it is working...